# The flow does not work as expected when run as site guest user in community

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-community, guest-user, lightning-templates

I have embedded the flow in a community template. The flow is accessible to the guest users, however flow does not work as expected e.g. it would not find records using the Get record element in flow. When I run it in salesforce, it seems to work fine. Not sure why it does not work when I run it in the community as a site guest user.

Thanks

Comment: Does the community user have access to the records you're trying to `get` in the flow?

Comment: oh I just noticed default external access in org wide sharing settings is private. Do I need to change it to public read?

Comment: if you change it to public, you will see an SFDC Health Check warning when you run that in Security Settings. You are better off with explicit sharing rules or sharing sets

Comment: I did change the org wide defaults for external users to 'public' to test this. It still does not work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a specific profile for Guest Users. If you give that profile access to the objects you want to expose, the Flow will work as expected.

Main docs are [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_flow_guestuser.htm&type=0).

A lot of things changed in Winter '20, so read up [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_user.htm).

Comment: Yes after giving the guest profile access to objects, setting org wide default settings and giving user "Run flow" permission, it worked fine.